# Is there any matrix s.t. $A^{-1} = -A?$

Tags: linear-algebra

My intuition says No, because if you multiply both members by $A$. you get $I = -A^2$ one member is positive and the other is negative which can not be.

Can someone confirm please?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. the matrix is squared and $2\times2$ and the field is over $\mathbb R.$

Comment: sorry i have deleted my answer

Comment: If the field is such that $-1$ is not a square (such as $\mathbb{R}$), then there exists such an $n$-by-$n$ matrix if and only if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and its negative.

Indeed, the are infinitely many real examples: let
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & t-a
\end{pmatrix} $$
($t$ thus being the trace of $A$). This has square
$$ A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
a^2 + bc & bt \\
ct & (a-t)^2+bc
\end{pmatrix}. $$
For the off-diagonal terms to be zero, we either have $t=0$ or $b,c=0$. The latter cannot happen if the entries are real since then we would have $a^2=-1$. Hence $t=0$, and then both other equations reduce to
$$ a^2+bc = -1. $$
A change of coordinates $2u=b+c$, $2v=b-c$ shows that this is the equation of a hyperboloid of one sheet. Hence any real matrix of the form
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & -a
\end{pmatrix} $$
with $a^2+bc=-1$ will work.

Comment: Thank you sir. Can you explain me what was wrong in my intuition it's more important to me than a counter-example

Comment: Why do you think for matrices, $A^2$ needs to have positive entries?

Comment: got it now. Thanks I messed things up when I thought matrices as numbers

Comment: i think you should solve  system of equation $I=-A^2$

Comment: @user21312  $A^2$ does not equal to $A.^2$ ,later one is used in matlab which is pointwise  square

Comment: Didn't you just write the same thing now?

Comment: @user21312 no ,$A^2$  is  $A*A$,  while $A.^2$ means  taking  square of each element of $A$

Answer (score 1):

here is example

A=[2 1 ;3 4]

```
A =

     2     1
     3     4
```

and two different example

```
>> A*A

ans =

     7     6
    18    19

>> A.^2

ans =

     4     1
     9    16
```

Comment: better to accept  @Chappers answer,  it  is just  matlab code,  you may upvote it

Comment: Thank you bro. the zero matrix isn't a valid example right?

Comment: zero matrix is matrix with  all elements  zero , why do you need it?

Comment: Just asking because it works but it seems to me like a stupid counter example

Comment: How is this answer an example of a matrix $A$ for which $A^{-1} = -A \text{?} \qquad$

Comment: @ Michael Hardy it is  not answer  for it, please follow comments

Comment: for zero matrix, there does not  exist its inverse, because it is singular or determinant is zero

Comment: mister  @MichaelHardy  did not like your $+1$  :D :D :D :D, it does not matter  anyway